# how to Check multiple conditions on multiple line belonging to variable size block of lines and return the main line

Tags: python, python-3.x, awk, sed

Basically my text file looks like this.

```
 **A: lorem ipsum verade(unique)**
 a: asd
 b: asd

 c: alsd
 d: def

**B: korem ipsum vladmir(unique)**
 c: fdh
 e: asd

**C: lorum ipsum vladmir(unique)**
 a: asd
 b: asd

 d: def
 e: asd
```

As one can see here let say example.txt have 3 main entries(A, B, C) having multiple data.
My question is hoe can I check Multiple condition for A eg i want all entries from A,B,C if a: asd and d: def. So output should be A and C.
Basically I want to know how to chexk multiple line while keeping track of line earlier.
I hope i made it clear.Just to remember this is a huge file so multiple loops need to be avoided if possible.

Comment: How do you determine what's a _main entry_? Uppercase character followed by a colon? Are the other entries always in a format `<lowercase character><colon><space><value><EOL>`?

Comment: yes that can be used or specific keyword for such purpose.

Comment: What's your expected output? Just `A & C` for your example?

Comment: Yes that would be enough.

Answer (score 1):

In AWK:

1. You should store all the lines from main entry in a array.
2. For every checked line where a:asd or d:def add 1 to variable(lets say "counter")
3. If you come across new main entry print array if counter is equal 2, then clear counter and array.

Comment: but the issue in this case would be that if here are multiple same entry then the counter will also increase but I want  exact match like both the parameters a and d should be there...

Comment: So make two "counters", for a param and b param

Answer (score 0):

If the strings desired to be searched are assigned to 'v1' and 'v2', respectively,

```
$ v2="a: asd"; v1="d: def"
$ awk -v v1="$v1" -v v2="$v2" '/\*\*.*\*\*/{s=substr($0,match($0,/\*\*.\:/)+2,1);next}{a[s]=a[s] $0}END{for(i in a)if(match(a[i],v1)&&match(a[i],v2))print i}' test.txt
A
C
```

The one-liner can be expanded as followed block,

```
$ cat awk-script
/\*\*.*\*\*/{
  s=substr($0,match($0,/\*\*.\:/)+2,1);
  next
}
{
  a[s]=a[s] $0
}
END{
  for(i in a)
    if(match(a[i],v1)&&match(a[i],v2))
      print i
}

$ awk -v v1="$v1" -v v2="$v2" -f awk-script test.txt
A
C
```

Brief explanation,

- `/\*\*.*\*\*/`: search the main entries
- `s=substr($0,match($0,/\*\*.\:/)+2,1)`: assign the value of the main entry to 's'
- `a[s]=a[s] $0`: assign the records belong to each main entry
- `match(a[i],v1)&&match(a[i],v2)`: check if 'v1' and 'v2' match the value in each main entry.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^\s*\*\*/{:a;x;//!bb;/a: asd/!bb;/d: def/!bb;p;:b;x;h;d};H;$!d;ba' file
```

Store  multi-line collections in the hold space. Before starting a new collection, check the hold space and print it out if it conforms to the requirements. At the end of the file check the hold space one last time.

The start of a collection is denoted by a line beginning `**` (or `**` with some leading white space). In order for a collection to printed, it must contain the strings `a: asd` and `d: def`, otherwise it is a false collection and is best forgotten. All other lines can be appended to the current collection.

Answer (score 0):

With python:

Create an empty list to store the selected blocks:
blocks=[]

Create flags to note if patterns found ('asd','def')
s_asd,s_def=False,False

Make an empy list for the current block:
blck=[]

Read the lines one by one and check them:
If the line contains the ** and the s_asd,s_def are True, then append the current block to 'blocks'.
And clear the current block('blck'), and set the flags to False.
If the line doesn't contain **, check for the 'asd' or 'def' pattern and set the corresponding flags.
Append the current line to 'blck'.

At the end of the cycle you must check again the flags and append the 'blck' to 'blocks' if neccessary.

Code example:

```
...
line=line.strip()
if line[:2]=="**" and line[-2:]=="**":
   if s_asd and s_def:
       blocks.append(blck)
       s_asd,s_def=False,False
   blck=[]
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
match($0,/[[:upper:]]:/) { prt(); key=substr($0,RSTART,1) }
{ rec = rec $0 ORS }
END { prt() }
function prt() {
    if ( (rec ~ /a: asd/) && (rec ~ /d: def/) ) {
        print key
    }
    rec = key = ""
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
A
C
```